# Spring Data JPA limit nested collection size as Pageable

Tags: java, spring-boot, collections, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

I'm using SpringBoot 2.0.4.

The idea is to retrieve a *Conversation* entity that contains a collection of *Message* objects. But I need a control over the size of messages collection e.g. retrieve only 20 latest or so.

```
@Entity
public class Conversation {
    //fields...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    //methods...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Message {
    //....
}
```

So when I'm retrieving a conversation by Id like this:

```
conversationRepository.findById(id)
```

How can I include only the x (e.g. 20) of latest messages?

Comment: If you want something that looks like a conversation, but actually has only 20 messages instead of all the messages of a conversation, then it's not a conversation. So, create a query to get the latest 20 messages of a conversation, and return a DTO containing these 20 messages and whatever other fields of the conversation you want to return.

Comment: @JBNizet, could you please post this message as an answer? I'm going to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In the `MessageRepository` interface, add:

```
@Query("select messages from Conversation c inner join c.messages messages where c = :conversation")
  public Page < Message > findByConversation(@Param("conversation") Conversation conversation, Pageable pageable);
```

To return the last 20 ( or even n ) records , you sort them by message id in descending order:

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 20, Sort.Direction.DESC, "id");
Page<Message> messages = repo.findByConversation(conversation, pageable); 
List<Message> last20MessageList = messages.getContent();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code for your case

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 20, Sort.Direction.DESC, "id");

Page<Message> lastPage = conversationRepository.findById(id, pageable);
// this is a list of the last 20 records
List<Message> latestMessage = lastPage .getContent();
```

Hope this help!